# drag and drop tiles inside surface view

Tags: java, android, surfaceview

Currently I am having an  application. it uses :

- surface view
- on the surface view , i split the screen based on width and height
- then based on the number of channels ( 4 /9/16 ) I create the divison to show the number of channels

  ```
  int width = getWidth();
  int height = getHeight();
  int offset = -miStartIndex / 4 * getWidth();
  for (int i = 0; i < mVideoArray.size(); i++)
  {
         int divWidth = width / 2;
         int divHeight = divWidth * 3 / 4;

          switch (i % 4)
          {
              case 0 :
                  setLocation(divWidth * 0 + offset, divHeight * 0 + mTop);
                  break;
             case 1 :
                  setLocation(divWidth * 1 + offset, divHeight * 0 + mTop);
                  break;
              case 2 :
                  setLocation(divWidth * 0 + offset, divHeight * 1 + mTop);
                  break;
              case 3 :
                  setLocation(divWidth * 1 + offset, divHeight * 1 + mTop);
                  offset += getWidth();.....
                  break;
              default :
                  break;
       }
  ```
- So with this code , i create 4 square to show the 4 channels
- In each channels i show live stream of some videos.

  ```
  channel 1, channel 2,
  channel 3, channel 4.
  ```

  Now my next feature that i need to implement is tile switching
  User can drag and drop between channels. e.g move the channel 2 to 4th postion.  Doing this it will show live stream as

  ```
  channel 1, channel 4,
  channel 3, channel 2.
  ```

  1. I dont know how to achieve this tile switching using surface view
  2. How to move one square (e.g ch 1 ) to another place (e.g ch3) inside surface view

I wish to check out possibilities how to achieve drag and drop between two squares in a surface view

Comment: how do you stream those videos?

Comment: I use a open source library to work on the live streams. Please help understand how to drag and drop between the squares as created  inside the surface view

Comment: use for example ViewDragHelper class

Comment: can you tell me how to use the ViewDrag Helper class for moving each view inside the surface view

Comment: see this for example: https://gist.github.com/pskink/b747e89c1e1a1e314ca6